# How to serve a Java application as Docker container and .war file?

Tags: build, gitlab, devops

Currently our company is creating individual software for B2B customers.

Some applications can be used for multiple customers.

Usually we can host the application in the cloud and deploy everything with Docker.
Running a GitLab pipeline and deploying etc. is fine for that.

Now we got some customers who rely on an external installation.
Since some of them still use Windows Server (2008 tho), I can not install a proper Docker environment on there and we need to install an Apache Tomcat and run the application inside the tomcat.

**Question:** How to deal with that? I would need a pipeline to create a docker image and a war file.
Simply create two completely independent pipelines?
Handle everything in a single pipeline?

Our current gitlab-ci.yml file for the .war

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s settings.xml -q -B"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test

install:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS install
  artifacts:
    name: "datahub-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - target/*.war
```

Comment: Is the same application for all your customers? I know it is hard but I was able to configure a proper docker environment in a windows machine. Do you have full access to Windows Server 2008 in order to install docker? Are you able to install or use a continuous integration server like Jenkins in your company?  Depending of your answers I have an option which enables you to deploy the docker container to any of your customers in a simple way!

Answer (score 1):

Using to separate delivery pipeline is preferable: you are dealing with two very installation processes, and you need to be sure which one is running for a given client.

Having two separate GitLab pipeline allows for said client to chose the right one.

Comment: What about the tests? Should they also run for each job?

Comment: @jdickel yes, but they could be defined only once (if they are platform agnostic), and that uunique test job could be chained from both pipelines.